# How to get the return of a command?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I'm developing a WebApp that sends commands for Linux.
For this I am using Javascript / jQuery on the client and Node.js on the server.
My code is this:

Client side

```
$("#myLink").click(function() {
    $.get('http://myHost:myPort', {cmd: "rhythmbox-client --print-playing"});
});
```

Server Side (commands.js)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/commands', function(req, res) {
    var command = exec(req.query.cmd);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This works and executes commands normally.
What I need is to get the return that this command generates, for example, if I run the command "rhythmbox-client --print-playing" in the terminal it will return me the name of the song that is currently playing.
And I would like to use this name in the HTML page of my application.

What should I change in my code to get the return generated by the command to be executed?

thank you
(Sorry my bad english)

Comment: Try adding `> some_file 2>&1` to the command, and looking for some_file on the server.  Then all you need to do is (1) make this file have a unique name each time, and (2) stream it back to the user.  **Warning: you are writing a security hole and strangers may execute bad things like rm or try to root your machine from the shell** but so long as you know that, have fun.

Comment: For more creative ideas see this post on reddit: [Creating a user from the web problem](http://www.reddit.com/r/php/comments/1l7baq/)

Comment: Yes @Paul, I will treat the commands received and remove words like "rm".

Answer (score 3):

Pass a callback function to exec to get the command output, like this:

```
var command = exec(req.query.cmd, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    res.send(stdout);
});
```

Comment: It seems that this is the right way.
Seeing the results on Firebug I saw that now there is a tab called HTML, but empty. :(

Comment: @Agneli you may explore express's documentation about response types.